# How to populate List with data from db using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I need to add data from db to a `List<Clients>`. I fetched data from db and now I'm not sure how to properly do it, what's the good pattern/standard for this kind of operation. Below you can find my code. I need to populate `List<Clients>`. I don't think I follow good practice here, I guess I could do it easier but don't know how exactly. And I don't think I return list with data here, I think I don't populate it properly.

```
    public class Clients
    {
        public Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IClientsRepository
    {
        Task<List<Clients>> ListAllClients();
    }

    public class ClientsRepository : IClientsRepository
    {
        private List<Clients> _clientsList;


        public ClientsRepository(MainDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        }

        public async Task<List<Clients>> ListAllClients()
        {
            _clientsList = new List<Clients>();

            var query = await _dbContext.ClientsTbl
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .Join(_dbContext.AddressTbl.AsNoTracking(),
                                client => client.Id,
                                address => address.ClientId,
                                (client, address) => new
                                {
                                    client.Id,
                                    client.Name,
                                    address.FullAddress
                                })
                                .ToListAsync();

            var allClients = query
                            .Select(s => new Clients 
                            { 
                                Id = s.Id,
                                Name= s.Name,
                                Address = s.FullAddress
                            });
            
            return _clientsList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign `_clientsList` any data?

Comment: Yes, I think that nowhere and just wanted to know how to populate it with data returned from `query`.

Comment: Hi,@mustafa00,I've updated my answer,have you tried like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Address entity has the property `address.ClientId`,and your client model contains the property  `Address`

The Address model and Client model has the one-to-one relationship

```
public partial class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public  partial class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? FullAddress { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }
```

you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) and select a solution to read the related data

for example:

```
var clients = await _context.Client.Include(x=>x.Address).ToListAsync();
```

now you could read read fulladdress through the navigation property:

```
clients[0].Address.FullAddress
```

Have you tried as below:

I added a property in client entity

```
public string? FullAddress { get; set; }

var clients = await _context.Client.AsNoTracking().Join(_context.Address.AsNoTracking(), x => x.Id, y => y.ClientId, (client, address) => new Client{ Id=client.Id, Name=client.Name, FullAddress=address.FullAddress }).ToListAsync();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use `Include` but the things is that my tables don't have foreign keys and can't be added (db-first approach). And I need to join them here explicitly. So I return data in `query` and need to populate `_clientsList`. So the issue is that I don't know how to populate `_clientsList` with this LINQ query.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Do Navigation properties work without defining and configuring FKs?

Comment: Hi,@Tolbxela,It would configure ClientId as FK by default,just similar with  configuring Id/ EntitynameId as key by default

Comment: Hi,@mustafa00 ,have you tried as what I 've updated?

Comment: Great, this is what I looked for. So crucial part was assigning fileds to Client in `new Clients {Id=...}`. So, I don't need to initialize `List<Clients>` in this part: `_clientsList = new List<Clients>();`, it's useless. Thanks, it works now, I return what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you have  `DbSet<Clients> ClientsTbl` in your MainDbContext, then you can simply return it like this.

```
return await _dbContext.ClientsTbl.ToListAsync();
```

I am not sure if you Join on `AddressTbl` using `string Address` is correct.

If you want to return `Clients` together with `Addresses`, then you should better create a [Relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) between them.

Like

```
public class Clients
{
   public Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }   
   public Address Address { get; set; }
    
}

public  partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FullAddress { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

You will need then a migration to apply the new relationship to the database. This also works for the Db first approach.

Then you can return your Clients together with Addresses, as @RuikaiFeng suggested.

```
return await _dbContext.ClientsTbl.Include(x=>x.Address).ToListAsync();
```

Please check the [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) about this.

Comment: The issue is that I need to follow db-first approach. There are no FK on tables. That's why I explicitly join both tables here. The issues is how to populate `_clientsList` with data from `query`.

Comment: The answer from @RuikaiFeng is better. I have overlooked the ClientId property.

Comment: Ok, so all in all I need to add FK to make it work smoothly. Let's say I add FK and join the tables as @Ruikai Feng shown in his post. My last, crucial question is: based on my example - how I can populate _clientsList now? Will this work out: `var _clientsList = await _context.Client.Include(x=>x.Address).ToListAsync();` given that I need to return `List<Clients>` type in `async Task`? Please let me know since this is what I'm really struggling with.